# Matlab reshape equivalent in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, linear-algebra

I'm currently porting a MATLAB library over to Python. As of right now, I am trying to keep the code as one-to-one as possible. I'm noticing some differences between `reshape` in Matlab vs Python that is causing some issues.

I've heard people talk about the difference in 'C' and 'Fortran' order. How numpy defaults to 'C' order and Matlab uses 'Fortran'. Below are two Python examples using both orders.

```py
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape((2,3,2))
>>> a
array([[[ 0,  1],
        [ 2,  3],
        [ 4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7],
        [ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]]])
>>> b = np.arange(12).reshape((2,3,2), order='F')
>>> b
array([[[ 0,  6],
        [ 2,  8],
        [ 4, 10]],

       [[ 1,  7],
        [ 3,  9],
        [ 5, 11]]])
```

Below is the matlab/octave equivalent to the above python code.

```matlab
octave:12> a = reshape((0:11), [3,2,2])
a =

ans(:,:,1) =

   0   3
   1   4
   2   5

ans(:,:,2) =

    6    9
    7   10
    8   11
```

Notice that each example yields a different result.

These examples are meant to illustrate the discrepancy that I'm referring to. The datasets that I'm working on in my project are significantly larger. I need to be able to reshape arrays in Python and be confident that it is performing the same reshape operations as it would in Matlab.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using a (2,3,2) shape in one, and (3,2,2) in the other?

```
In [82]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape((3,2,2), order='F')
In [83]: arr
Out[83]: 
array([[[ 0,  6],
        [ 3,  9]],

       [[ 1,  7],
        [ 4, 10]],

       [[ 2,  8],
        [ 5, 11]]])
In [84]: arr[:,:,0]
Out[84]: 
array([[0, 3],
       [1, 4],
       [2, 5]])
In [85]: arr[:,:,1]
Out[85]: 
array([[ 6,  9],
       [ 7, 10],
       [ 8, 11]])
```

===

Looking a strides may help identify the differences between `c` and `f` orders

```
In [86]: arr.shape
Out[86]: (3, 2, 2)
In [87]: arr.strides
Out[87]: (8, 24, 48)
```

Notice how the smallest steps, 1 element (8 bytes) is taken in first dimension.

Contrast that with a `C` order:

```
In [89]: np.arange(12).reshape(2,2,3)
Out[89]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5]],

       [[ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]]])
In [90]: np.arange(12).reshape(2,2,3).strides
Out[90]: (48, 24, 8)
```

===

OK lets try the (2,3,2) shape:

```
>> a = reshape((0:11),[2,3,2])
a =

ans(:,:,1) =

   0   2   4
   1   3   5

ans(:,:,2) =

    6    8   10
    7    9   11
```

Samething with order 'F':

```
In [94]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape((2,3,2), order='F')
In [95]: arr
Out[95]: 
array([[[ 0,  6],
        [ 2,  8],
        [ 4, 10]],

       [[ 1,  7],
        [ 3,  9],
        [ 5, 11]]])
In [96]: arr[:,:,0]
Out[96]: 
array([[0, 2, 4],
       [1, 3, 5]])

>> squeeze(a(1,:,:))
ans =

    0    6
    2    8
    4   10
In [98]: arr[0,:,:]
Out[98]: 
array([[ 0,  6],
       [ 2,  8],
       [ 4, 10]])
```

Comment: `np.arange(12).reshape(2,3,2)` in Python yields a different results than `reshape((0:11),[2,3,2])` in matlab. This is due to the indexing differences between the two languages. For 3 dimensional arrays, in Python it is `arr[z,y,x]` and in Matlab it is `arr(y,x,z)`.